# replace values in a column with the mean of last 5 preceding values of a group in the column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have a column with monthly return values with respect to the preceding month, i.e. all values are around 0.0, except sometimes the return equals -1, with the following value in the column begin very high e.g. 300. My issue now is changing all values equal to -1 and their following high values. I can't delete the values because then I'd delete the month which is not a good thing for the other columns. Hence I need to change the values -1 to some average over the last lets say 4 preceding values. Same thing being for the high values, the one after the -1 value. Another thing the replacement average should be the average over a group inside the column not the average of the whole column.

stock_data <- stock_data |>
group_by(gvkey) |>
mutate(ret_excess2 = ifelse(is.na(ret_excess), mean(ret_excess, na.rm = TRUE), ret_excess),
ret_excess2[which(ret_excess2 == -1)] = mean(ret_excess2),
ret_excess2[which(ret_excess2 == -1) + 1] = mean(ret_excess2)
)

I hope you understand the code im after. Most importantly I can't figure out how to get the mean of the last 5 values of the group in the column. Instead of just the group average as im trying in the code above.

Comment: Please provide `dput(stock_data)` output in order to make your issue reproducible.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg